# How to put all the button in the same row?

Tags: java, swt

I created several link button.

I want that all the buttons will be in the same row.

Every time that I inserted new button then it got to the next row.

```
public void createControls(Composite parent) {
    myComposite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);

    GridLayout detailsSideGridLayout = new GridLayout();
    detailsSideGridLayout.numColumns = 1;
    myComposite.setLayout(detailsSideGridLayout);
    GridDatamyGridData = new GridData();
    myGridData.horizontalAlignment = SWT.FILL;
    myGridData.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
    myGridData.verticalAlignment = SWT.FILL;
    myGridData.grabExcessVerticalSpace = true;
    myComposite.setLayoutData(myGridData);
    deComposite = new Composite(myComposite, SWT.NONE);
    RowLayout dgGridLayout = new RowLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL);
    deComposite.setLayout(deGridLayout);

    GridData deGridData = new GridData();
    deGridData.horizontalAlignment = SWT.FILL;
    deGridData.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;

    LinkLabel createDetailsde = createDetailsde(deComposite);
    createDetailsde.setLayoutData(deGridData);
          //Add another button
    createLinkLabel(createDetailsde)

     myComposite.layout();
   private LinkLabel createDetailsde(Composite detailsComposite) {
    // TODO check resource manager implementation

    LinkLabel linkLabel = new LinkLabel(detailsComposite, SWT.NONE);
    linkLabel.setText("test"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    return linkLabel;

}

    private LinkLabel createLinkLabel(Composite detailsComposite) {
    LinkLabel linkLabel = new LinkLabel(detailsComposite, SWT.NONE);
    linkLabel.setText("test2"); //$NON-NLS-1$

    return linkLabel;
}
```

I got error message
The error is org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData cannot be cast to org.eclipse.swt.layout.RowData

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `GridLayout` you are using only has one column (`deGridLayout.numColumns = 1;`). There are two things you can do:

1. Define the `GridLayout` to have as many columns as you want to have `Button`s
2. Use a `RowLayout` with `SWT.HORIZONTAL` instead (you won't have to define the number of items here)

Here is some example code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

    Group first = new Group(shell, SWT.NONE);
    first.setText("RowLayout");
    first.setLayout(new RowLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));

    Group second = new Group(shell, SWT.NONE);
    second.setText("GridLayout");
    second.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, false));

    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
    {
        new Button(first, SWT.PUSH).setText("Button " + i);
        new Button(second, SWT.PUSH).setText("Button " + i);
    }

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

This is what it looks like:

[image]

---

The problem with your code is that you are trying to add `GridData` to a `Composite` using `RowLayout`. That's not possible. Your code can be fixed (and massively compressed) like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));

    Composite myComposite = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
    myComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
    myComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    Composite deComposite = new Composite(myComposite, SWT.NONE);
    deComposite.setLayout(new RowLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));

    Label createDetailsde = createDetailsde(deComposite);

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}

private static Label createDetailsde(Composite detailsComposite)
{
    Label linkLabel = new Label(detailsComposite, SWT.NONE);
    linkLabel.setText("test");
    return linkLabel;
}
```

Comment: The composite myComposite is GridLayout then I got dump. I updated my code

Comment: @user1365697 _"I got dump"_ What's that supposed to mean?

Comment: I think because I have two types of layout composite .The dump raise when detailsComposite.layout();

Comment: @user1365697 What's "dump"? If you mean the stack trace, then please add it to your question.

Comment: The error is org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData cannot be cast to org.eclipse.swt.layout.RowData

Comment: @user1365697 The line you are referencing (`detailsComposite.layout()`) isn't in the code you provided. Please create a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (like my code above) that I can use to reproduce your problem.

Comment: what was the change in your code  ? I didn't find it. P.S thanks for the help

Comment: @user1365697 I just removed the part where you assign the `GridData` to the `Composite` using `RowLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

```
deGridLayout.numColumns = 1;
```

If you have one column, every element will start a new row. Define a GridLayout with one row.

Answer (score 0):

The error is that you've defined a GridLayout with 1 column

```
GridLayout deGridLayout = new GridLayout();
deGridLayout.numColumns = 1;
deComposite.setLayout(deGridLayout);
```

Hence, every time you "add" a component to the panel, you'll fill-up the current row and will go for the next. Besides that, your use of GridLayout is rather strange. Use the constructor and define it's behavior instead of accessing numColumns.

```
GridLayout deGridLayout = new GridLayout(10, 1); //Room for 10 components in one row.
deComposite.setLayout(deGridLayout);
```

Question here is though; how many components (columns) do you need in your row?

Comment: The contructor `GridLayout(int, int)` is not defined. The second parameter is a `boolean` stating if the columns should have the same width. The number of rows doesn't have to be specified, it's dynamic.

Comment: @Baz; are you sure? GridLayout -- not GridBag, just Grid... http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html#GridLayout(int,%20int)

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. It' [SWT `GridLayout`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/layout/GridLayout.html), not Swing/AWT.

Comment: It is SWT AND NOT AWT/Swing